# Begründung für Komma

Tags: subordinate-clause, comma, punctuation, adverbial

Mit einem Arbeitskollegen habe ich heute eine Einladung verfasst. In zwei Fällen waren wir uns bei Kommas uneinig:

**Fall 1**

> Wie zuvor abgesprochen, findet dieser Kurs [...]<sup>1</sup> in Berlin statt.

**Fall 2**

> Wir freuen uns drauf, Sie bald in Berlin begrüßen zu dürfen!

Welche der beiden Kommas sind richtig gesetzt? Welche Regeln liegen dem Setzen zugrunde?

<sup>1 Angabe von Tag, Datum und Uhrzeit</sup>

Comment: Was habt ihr denn bislang selbst herausgefunden und was ist daran unklar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Zu Fall 1

> Wie zuvor abgesprochen(,) findet dieser Kurs in Berlin statt.

Das **Komma kann, muss aber nicht** gesetzt werden. Begründung: Der erste Teil ist ein formelhafter Nebensatz. Normalerweise grenzt man Nebensätze gemäß [§ 74](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par74) des amtl. Regelwerks mit Komma ab, doch für die formelhaften gilt [§ 76](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par76), wonach das Komma weggelassen werden kann (aber nicht muss).

#### Zu Fall 2

> Wir freuen uns drauf, Sie bald in Berlin begrüßen zu dürfen!

Das **Komma muss** gesetzt werden. Begründung: Der zweite Teil ist eine vom Verweiswort *drauf* abhängige Infinitivgruppe, und gemäß [§ 75 (3)](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par75-3) des amtl. Regelwerks grenzt man Infinitivgruppen, die von einem Verweiswort abhängig sind, mit Komma ab. Zu prüfen ist noch, ob eines der Zusätze E1 oder E2 von § 75 die Bedingung (3) wieder auflöst. Dies ist hier nicht der Fall, denn [E1](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par75E1) betrifft nur bloße Infinitive (wenn also *zu dürfen* allein stünde), und [E2](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par75E2) betrifft nur Infinitivgruppen, die nicht bereits durch § 75 (1)–(3) geregelt sind.

Answer (score 3):

In beiden Fällen dürft ihr euch beliebig lange streiten und habt trotzdem beide recht: Beide Kommas sind erlaubt, aber nicht verpflichtend (waren es aber nach den "alten" Rechtschreibregeln).

Warum:

### Fall 1:

*Eigentlich* gehört der Nebensatz "Wie bereits besprochen" durch ein Komma abgesetzt (Rechtschreibregeln §74). Es handelt sich dabei um einen Nebensatz mit einer Partizipialkonstruktion, der üblicherweise durch ein Komma abgesetzt werden muss. §76 gibt aber die Ausnahme an, dass bei formelhaften Nebensätzen das Komma weggelassen kann, gibt als Beispiel

> Wie bereits gesagt(,) verhält sich die Sache anders.

was ziemlich genau deinem Beispiel entspricht.

### Fall 2:

Auch hier gehört *eigentlich* ein Komma zwischen Hauptsatz und Nebensatz, denn Regel §75 sagt "Infinitivgruppen grenzt man mit Komma ab, wenn eine der folgenden Bedingungen erfüllt ist....(3) die Infinitivgruppe hängt von einem Korrelat oder einem Verweiswort ab" und nennt als Beispiel

> Es missfällt mir, diesen Vertrag zu unterzeichnen.

was wiederum deinem Beispiel entspricht - Weicht diese Regel dann aber in E1: auf:

> E1: Wenn ein bloßer Infinitiv vorliegt, können in den Fallgruppen (2) und (3) die Kommas weggelassen werden, sofern keine Missverständnisse entstehen.

(Was in deinem Beispiel ebenfalls der Fall ist).

Ganz allgemein läuft man allerdings am wenigsten Gefahr, was falsch zu machen, wenn man das Komma in solchen Fällen setzt. Meiner Meinung nach sorgen Kommas hier auch für eine bessere Übersichtlichkeit.

Comment: Hmm, meint "bloßer Invinitiv" nicht etwas wie "Es missfällt mir zu unterzeichnen."? Ich dachte eigentlich bisher, der erweiterte Infinitv mit zu muss auch nach neuer Rechtschreibung mit Komma abgetrennt werden.

Comment: @Roland "bloßer Infinitiv" ist weiter gedacht. "Ich versuche morgen pünktlich zu sein" oder "Wir bitten das Produkt bei Nichtgefallen zurückzusenden" sind weitere Beispiele, wo man das KOmma weglassen darf. Du hast allerdings recht: Sicherer ist es, das Komma in solchen Fällen zu setzen, da läuft man am wenigsten Gefahr, was falsch zu machen.

Comment: @tofro Danke für die Antwort! Ich meine jedoch, dass die [unteren Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71924/16543) korrekt bestimmt hat was bloße Infinitive im Kontext von E1 sind. Daher habe ich diese akzeptiert.